# Use infopath for a lookup column different site collections

Tags: 2013, infopath, lookup-column

I have a client who has 2013 SP and has 3 different site collections.

They have an infopath form that is used. However they require they need to get information from a different list in other site collections.

They have a PO approval form and IM (cost plan of project) approval. The PO and IM cost approval sit on different site collections.

"What we would also like the PO form to do is look at the PO list and SUM the costs of all the PO that are assigned the IM of the current PO that is being raised. So one look at the form when raising a PO you can select the IM it is for and it will populate the form with the total spend allowed for the IM and the total spend so far with POs for that IM. "

Unforunlety there SP system is a legacy setup due to older versions data restriction of 4GB per Site collection (so I am informed). So migrating data to another SC is not possible yet.

Can this be achievable, if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With infopath you can create an admin approved form. With this type of form you can use code-behind where in C# or VB you can achieve anything you need - but troubleshooting issues on this kind of solution is sometimes tricky (I usually end up with an DEBUG view where I can print out variables, errors encountered and such)

None of the SP versions had an limitation of 4GB per site collection. One soft limit is 200GB per content DB.

Comment: So this isnt just available OOTB but it needs to be done by custom code?

Comment: Yes because out of the box you don't have an lookup column that can query across site collections.

Comment: Thanks! Just a last question for the solution is it possible to do a Web service call within infopath? Like a call to lists.asmx and GetListItems with some parameter? 

If no I guess a coded solution will have to be the only way!

Comment: I think you can do it by setting up secondary data source, but as I used the only code behind enabled form i haven't really tried that (it made more sense to keep as much as you can in code behind otherwise figuring out in form what does what can take some time)